# How to protocol acess to specific packages or jars from EventDispatchThread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

We have a 15yo "Fat Client" Swing application (I would classify it as "legacy", but we have nothing to replace it yet). It loads the data (object graph) from our DC over the Internet, and the data for some clients runs in the multi gigabytes (de-compressed and de-serialized).

My problem is that the object-graph is access both from the EventDispatchThread and from background threads *without synchronisation*. 15 years ago, this caused no problem, but now, with everyone using multi-core processors, we get random synchronisation-related non-reproducible bugs almost every day. Some operations on the model can take several minutes, so we cannot block the EventDispatchThread by running those operations there. We need to refactor the UI so that it doesn't directly access the model, and only work on a "copy" of the data it needs (or at least, I don't see any other solution that would not cause the UI to freeze).

Unfortunately, our codebase is huge (about 2M LOC by now, if we include everything), so that's going to be a *big* refactoring.

What I'm looking for is some mean of logging "unsynchronized" access to the "model" (object graph) from within the EventDispatchThread (or any specific thread, based on some white/black-list), *only in test/development*, so we can progressively patch the code.

So, how could I detect access to the model/object-graph, from within the EventDispatchThread, *without having to manually modify the whole codebase with checks*?

I'm hoping this can be done with some combination of special ClassLoader/SecurityManager/Bytecode-Manipulation, but I don't know where to start looking.

ATM, the model and UI classes are partly mixed together in the same packages and/or jars, but I believe separating them should be possible in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: You could try [`CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager)

Comment: @CatalinaIsland I did. But it works the wrong way around; I don't want to know that UI objects are accessed outside of the EventDispatchThread, I want to know that non-UI objects (model) are accessed inside the EventDispatchThread.